# asp.net mvc alpahetical naviagation populating record problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to implement the alphabetical navigation like A B C D and so on ,when the user press any alphabet ,it will populate the table with the record based on the alphabet.Can someone help to correctly implement that . here is my start. **Basically i am having problem in populating the records**. on clicking the alphabet it doesn't do anything.

```
Manage User  View

   <%= Ajax.ActionLink("a", "GetUser", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Alp = "a" }), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", HttpMethod = "Post" })%>
 <%= Ajax.ActionLink("b", "GetUser", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Alp = "b" }), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", HttpMethod = "Post" })%>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("c", "GetUser", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Alp = "c" }), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", HttpMethod = "Post" })%>

    <div id="divGrid"> 
    <% Html.RenderPartial("ManageUs", this.Model);  %>
</div>
```

ManageUs UserControl

```
    Manage User</h2>
  <%  Response.Write("Page "); Response.Write("<b>" + ViewData.Model.PageNumber + "</b>"); Response.Write(" Of "); Response.Write("<b>" + ViewData.Model.PageCount + "</b>"); %>
<table>
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>
            User Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Email Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Phone
        </th>
        <th>
            Group
        </th>
        <th>
            Organization
        </th>
        <th>
        Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead> 
      <tbody> 
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>

    <tr id="row-<%: item.int_UserId %>">
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.vcr_UserName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.vcr_EmailAddress) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.vcr_Phone) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.GroupUserWise(item.int_UserId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.OrganizationUsersWise(item.int_UserId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href=' <%= Url.Action("Edit", new { id=item.int_UserId }) %>'>
                <img src="../../Content/images/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a> <a href=' <%= Url.Action("Details", new { id=item.int_UserId }) %>'>
                <img src="../../Content/images/add.png" alt="Details" /></a>
            <%--  <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.int_UserId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "table", HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Delete User with User ID:" + item.int_UserId + " UserName Name:" + item.vcr_UserName, OnBegin = "hide" })%> |--%>
            <%= Ajax.AjaxImageActionLink("../../Content/images/delete.png", "Delete", "DeleteRecord", new { id = item.int_UserId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "msgdiv",LoadingElementId = "divLoading"  })%>
            <%= Ajax.AjaxImageActionLink("../../Content/images/add.png", "Change Password", "ChangePasswos", new { id = item.int_UserId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "msgdiv" })%>
        </td>
    </ tr>

    <% } %>
       </tbody> 
</table>


 <div class="pager">
    <%= Ajax.Pager(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" },
             ViewData.Model.PageSize, ViewData.Model.PageNumber, ViewData.Model.TotalItemCount, new { controller = "User", action = "ManageUser" })%>
</div>
```

Get User Action

```
 public ActionResult GetUser(string Alp)
    {
        var list = _db.Users.Where(m=>m.vcr_UserName.StartsWith(Alp));

            return PartialView("ManageUs", list);



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but try to pass the parameter like this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("a", "GetUser", new { Alp = "a" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", HttpMethod = "Post" })%>
```

Also, did you checked if the controller method get hit in debug mode? Are the parameter passed correctly (does it looks okay on the other side)?

Comment: yes the parameter is passing correctly and the controller get hit on the debug mode